# GeoServer image generation error

Tags: geoserver, wms, error, getmap

I'm using GeoServer + PostGIS and I got an image generation error when I test my layer in WMS GetMap request:

`http://localhost:8089/geoserver/pmc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=pmc:utbs&styles=&bbox=272206.156,7448903.5,303656.5,7484798.0&width=448&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image/jpeg`

This is the image error:

[image: image error]

Comment: Could you please check the log file under .../geoserver-x.x.x/logs folder and see what is happening when you make this request.

Comment: does it also do this when you look at the preview page?

Comment: Yes! This is when a look at the preview page, but i think it's my video driver.

Comment: One thing that is wrong with the request is the bbox appears to be in metres, but the projection EPSG:4326 uses degrees.  So I think I would expect some error.